# while creating CSR file that private key is missing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, keychain, csr

keychainAccess-> certificateAssistant -> Request a certificate for certificate authority.

After that i didn't see any private key under the name of my created csr file.

I am creating csr for pushNotification.

While my app is in under development i have created private key easily ,while i am trying to create csr for distribution i didn't see the private key.

1.That previous PrivateKey is enough for the distribution certificate?

Please somebody help me for clear understanding about keychain and private key creation.

Comment: @kishore_k have you done?

Comment: @VvkAghera i have followed the same way gave by reywenderlich :( . some thing wrong in my keychain access

Comment: could you try with restarting the Keychain Access?

Comment: yes @VvkAghera and i can seen the certificate now it is under the appid name not in csr file name

Comment: okay. some times this problem is faced becaus of Keychain Access is not refresh.